# PHP mcrypt missing in OpenShift

Tags: php, joomla, openshift, openshift-php-cartidges

While installing Joomla on OpenShift message was shown that

> "PHP mcrypt should be installed or some features of Joomla might not
>   work properly".

Now the Joomla sample website opens sometimes and sometimes doesn't but shows the message:

> "Application is not available. The application is currently not
>   serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is
>   still starting.".

Is it due to `PHP mcrypt`. I also tried using PHP 5.5 and 5.6. How can I solve this problem and install `PHP mcrypt`? Also the Joomla setup wizard was not rendering properly. But I installed it anyways.

Comment: see the details for installation of [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php)

Comment: mcrypt will be removed in PHP 7.1, you should think about migrating to something else.

Comment: @Tiger But how can I install mcrypt in OpenShift? As I cannot have sudo previliges in the terminal in it's pod.

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.